# Is it possible to get stream status from this site?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

The only part where I found anything like 'online' was in some javascript code and I have no idea how to access that..

This is the [site](http://cs.twitch.tv/absolutelegends) in question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the API for TwitchTV/JustinTV, info about it can be found at the url below.

http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Stream/list

Here is a sample JSON-result from the channel you linked.

http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=absolutelegends